# Why won't the relative image path work in my React app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

[image: My directory structure]

I have a React app wherein I pass a relative image URL into a component as a prop...

```
<TechListItem imgSrc="../assets/images/javascript.png" itemName="JavaScript" />
```

And the prop is fed into the src attribute...

```
const TechListItem = (props) => {
return (
    <ListGroup.Item className="listItem">
        <img className="listImage" src={ props.imgSrc } alt={ props.itemName }/>
        <p className="itemName">{ props.itemName }</p>
    </ListGroup.Item>
);
}
```

I've tested out other instances of the same component with absolute paths from other sources...

```
<TechListItem imgSrc="https://via.placeholder.com/75" itemName="React" />
```

And they work just fine.

I've inspected the would-be image in my page and tried opening the image address (http://localhost:3000/assets/images/javascript.png) in Chrome, but nothing shows up. When I look in the network tab, it says the response code for the image is 304. I've tried emptying and hard-reloading after disabling the cache from dev tools. This gets me a 200 response, but the image still doesn't show up, either in my page or when I open the image in a new tab. Really not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such path does not exist in runtime, perhaps you should try one of the next approaches:

```
// import
import ImgSrc from '../assets/images/javascript.png';
<TechListItem imgSrc={ImgSrc}/>

// or require
<TechListItem imgSrc={require('../assets/images/javascript.png')}/>
```

Comment: Thank you! The import solution worked for me. So importing it from the source at which I'm passing it in makes the image available at run-time but the way I had it set up doesn't?

Comment: True, exactly as you said.